# What are the two math symbols here and how to get them in Latex?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I have been trying in vain to get the names for the below two math symbols and how to use them in Latex. Anyone who could help me please?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: For future independence: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character

Comment: Hint: Show the eqation that contains the symbol you are looking for highlighted. And welcome by the way.

Comment: The first comment did the trick. Thank you very much. The equation did not have any mention about the symbol used. It is a homework assignment that just says solve G = ... and V = .....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\mathcal` but I think your question will be closed as duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document} 

\[
\mathcal{G} \quad \mathcal{V}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If the scale is preserved, the second symbols seems rather to be a variant of $\nu$.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke You're right, also the G is not completely identical, let's wait for the OP showing the complete equation.